# couchbase cbimport not in the bin folder

Tags: database, couchbase

I am using the latest Couchbase Server 6.0 Community Edition and have the bin folder under the application folder as this documentation suggests

/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin

(I am using OSX)

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cli-intro.html

but when I try to use the cbimport as from the documentation here . https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/tools/cbimport.html
It does not appear to be in the bin or tools folder. So how should I invoke the command? I also tried couchbase-cli then cbimport

the commands I have tried

```
cd "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin"
```

`./cbimport json -c http://localhost:8091/ -u admin -p password -b commonDB -d ccData.json -f lines -g %key%`

```
-bash: ./cbimport: No such file or directory
```

`./couchbase-cli cbimport json -c http://localhost:8091/ -u admin -p password -b commonDB -d ccData.json -f lines -g %key%`


`ERROR: argument : invalid choice: 'cbimport' (choose from 'setting-alert', 'setting-notification', 'server-eshell', 'server-add', 'setting-security', 'node-init', 'collect-logs-status', 'ssl-manage', 'setting-xdcr', 'reset-admin-password', 'collect-logs-stop', 'recovery', 'rebalance-status', 'bucket-list', 'setting-index', 'group-manage', 'setting-master-password', 'cluster-init', 'user-manage', 'host-list', 'master-password', 'rebalance', 'setting-ldap', 'xdcr-replicate', 'rebalance-stop', 'cluster-edit', 'setting-autofailover', 'setting-audit', 'bucket-edit', 'bucket-delete', 'setting-password-policy', 'eventing-function-setup', 'server-info', 'setting-cluster', 'bucket-flush', 'failover', 'setting-autoreprovision', 'setting-compaction', 'bucket-create', 'bucket-compact', 'server-list', 'server-readd', 'admin-role-manage', 'collect-logs-start', 'xdcr-setup')`

the content that is in the bin

`bin username$ ls
c_rehash            couchbase-server
cbbackup            couchdb
cbbackupwrapper         couchjs
cbbrowse_logs           couchjs.tpl
cbcollect_info          ct_run
cbcompact           dbdiff
cbdocloader         dump-guts
cbdump-config           dump-stats
cbenable_core_dumps.sh      epmd
cbepctl             erl
cbft                escript
cbft-bleve          escript-wrapper
cbindex             forestdb_dump
cbindexperf         generate_cert
cbindexplan         gometa
cblogredaction          goport
cbq             gosecrets
cbq-engine          goxdcr
cbq.old             gozip
cbrecovery          indexer
cbrestore           install
cbrestorewrapper        jeprof
cbsasladm           kv_trace_dump
cbstats             mcbp_packet_printer
cbtransfer          mcctl
cbvbucketctl            mclogsplit
cbvdiff             mcstat
cbworkloadgen           mctimings
couch_compact           memcached
couch_dbck          mossScope
couch_dbdump            moxi
couch_dbinfo            openssl
couch_view_file_merger      priv
couch_view_group_cleanup    projector
couch_view_group_compactor  saslauthd-port
couch_view_index_builder    sigar_port
couch_view_index_updater    tools
couchbase-cli           vbmap`

The cbimport tools simply does not seem to be in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**cbimport** will be part of the Couchbase Community from Couchbase 6.5 onwards (which should be released soon). 
Here is the link to the issue: https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-36651 (You can sign up to view it)

In the meantime, you can download and install the EE version for development.